# Protege: property domain restrictions using other properties

Tags: class, properties, ontology, protege, restrictions

I'm creating my first ontology with protege 5.2 and I'm running into some trouble.

Let's say I have the following Classes:

`Gender` with subclasses `Female` and `Male`

`Human` with subclasses `Patient` and `Doctor`

`Disease` with subclass `Cancer` with subclass `Prostate_Cancer`

and the properties:

`hasDisease` (doman: `Patient`, range: `Disease`)

`hasGender` (domain: `Patient`, range: `Gender`)

Now I want to specify that a `Patient` who `hasDisease` `Prostate_Cancer` is a `Patient` who also `hasGender` `Male`.

Is this possible without creating new classes?

Comment: Shouldn't `Female` and `Male` be individuals, not classes? Or there exist individuals like `BrutalMale` etc.?

Comment: I think so too, but the exercise specifically asks for this - I love your example though

Comment: Should the domain of `hasGender` not be `Human` rather than `Patient`?

Comment: Then please paste here full text of that exercise.

Comment: The exercise sheet is copyrighted so I cannot post it here. Yet I can assure you it asks for a class hierarchy and also the domain of `hasGender` being `Patient`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Protege you can achieve this by adding a general class axiom:

```
hasDisease some Prostate_Cancer SubClassOf: Male
```

Then whenever you have an individual with a disease that is prostate cancer, the reasoner will infer that the individual is a `Male`.

You could model this as

```
hasDisease some Prostate_Cancer SubClassOf: hasGender some Male
```

as @StanislavKralin suggested, but then the reasoner will not infer that an individual is `Male` whenever it has prostate cancer. The reason for this is two fold:

(1) Domain and range restrictions merely state that whenever two individuals are linked via that property, the the first individual will be of the type of whatever is specified in the domain and the second individual will be of whatever type is specified as the range.

(2) In reality an ontology has infinite many inferences. To be usable tools cannot provide infinite inferences. Hence, tools like Protege only provide inferences for which there are named classes, i.e. like `Male`. Classes like `hasGender some Male` is referred to as anonymous classes and are not displayed as inferences.

Comment: Or maybe `... SubClassOf: hasGender some Male`, following their strange modelling approach (as well as I understand it).

Comment: You could do it like that, though the problem will be if you then have an individual that has prostate cancer, it will **not** infer that the individual is `Male`.

Comment: It seems that individuals of `Gender` are not people, perhaps the OP means something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44387574, i. e. there are many genders, and some of them are `Male` genders etc.